# NativeScript - how to use SASS variables all over the scss in the app?

Tags: css, angular, sass, nativescript

I'm building an app with NativeScript 6.4.1 and Angular 8. I want to use [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) with it because I like the features that come with SASS such as variable names.

My graphic designer has provided a number of colors that I will use app-wide on different pages so the SASS variables for the hex colors is going to be good.

I have installed

```
"node-sass": "4.12.0",
"sass": "^1.23.7",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
```

app.scss

```
@import '~@nativescript/theme/css/core.css';

@import 'variables';
```

The problem that I have is my SASS variables don't seem to be available in my component scss files.

home.component.scss

```
.home-panel{
vertical-align: center; 
font-size: 20;
margin: 15;
background-color: $navy_blue; //this does not exist
}
```

variables.scss

```
$navy_blue: #105195;
$vivid_cerulean: #28abe2;
$white: #ffffff;
$dark_navy_blue: #063260;
$light_grey: #eeeeee;
$error_red: #eb2026;
```

Here is a playground to play with but it's not my real set-up: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=aDZ7lZ

How can I use the variables in any scss folder or file?

I would prefer not to import the variables file all over the place.

Comment: does it give undefined error?

Comment: I don't see any issues on my end, it works and shows background in navy blue. But FYI, you don't have to add SCSS file that's already imported into styleUrls. Also generally the variable file is suffixed with an underscore (_), so it won't be actually created. Refer SCSS docs for more info.

Comment: Sure you can, but you will have to import variables file into scope which you did in `new-file.scss`. But you don't have to add it to styleUrls.

Comment: @Manoj I updated the playground again with more clarity about the problem.

Comment: There is no alternative solution, you must include variable scss file in all component specific scss file, without that the compiler wouldn't know what you are looking for. If you need this badly, I would suggest you to go through webpack docs, you might find a workaround for injecting your variable by default.

Comment: @Manoj if you put that as an answer then I would upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no alternative solution, you must include variable scss file in all component specific scss file, without that the compiler wouldn't know what you are looking for.

If you need this badly, I would suggest you to go through [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/), you might find a workaround for injecting your variables by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just import that variable.scss file inside your component.scss file

Or,
you can also declare your variables like

```
:root {
    --variable1: #fff;
    --variable2: #ddd;
}
```

and use it like,

```
color: var(--variable1)
```

inside your component.scss

**UPDATE**

I guess I solved your problem,
check out this https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=aDZ7lZ&v=2

Problem was that for home component in this example you were using css file so it was not able recognise scss syntax, I have fixed that in posted playground

**UPDATE**
Just use,

```
@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./home.component.scss"],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
...
}
```

This uses all the global styles without a need to import .scss files

Glad to help you

Comment: I tried the :root thing and it didn't work. Importing it all over kind of sucks but it will work.

Comment: @user1261710 is your style file of type .css or .scss? where you want to use this imported variable.

Comment: .scss is the file type.

Comment: why is it app.css in your question?

Comment: I have a production environment that is not in my question. I can't post the code for my work project on here. I have app.scss and _variables.scss. I tried to use the :root{} technique and it didn't work. The colors are not rendered. I can try to change my NS playground project too.

Comment: Can you change your NS Playground I will be able to help you out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211638/discussion-between-user1261710-and-indrajeet-nikam).

Comment: @user1261710 I guess I have resolved the issue, can you please upvote and accept it as answer if it solves your problem (small favor)  Also check this NS playground for reference https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=cBPYCs&v=3